# How do I changed the java version properly for a given maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to run a spring boot project with VS Code, following [a tutorial](https://fullstackdeveloper.guru/2020/05/01/how-to-integrate-sqlite-database-with-spring-boot/) and [its git repo](https://github.com/vijaysrj/sqlitedemo).

Here is `SqliteDemoApplication`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SqliteDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SqliteDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is part of `SQLDialect`

```
public class SQLDialect extends Dialect {
    public SQLDialect() {
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
        registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
...
        registerFunction("substring", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StringType.INSTANCE));
    }
    public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
    }
...
    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is `Person`

```
@Entity
public class Person {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
 
    private String name;
 
    private String message;
 
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 
    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    /**
     * @return the message
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
 
    /**
     * @param message the message to set
     */
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
 
}
```

Here is `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlitedemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sqlitedemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Sqlite Integration</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.16.1</version>
 
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The original project worked as expected and added 2 records to sqlite db.

However, when I changed the java.version to `<java.version>16</java.version>` in pom.xml, I got the following error

```
2021-05-02 06:52:09.236  WARN 68319 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/Users/ubuntu/dev/javaXP/spring_boot/spring02/sqlitedemo/target/classes/com/example/sqlitedemo/Person.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/Users/ubuntu/dev/javaXP/spring_boot/spring02/sqlitedemo/target/classes/com/example/sqlitedemo/Person.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
2021-05-02 06:52:09.284 ERROR 68319 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/Users/ubuntu/dev/javaXP/spring_boot/spring02/sqlitedemo/target/classes/com/example/sqlitedemo/Person.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/Users/ubuntu/dev/javaXP/spring_boot/spring02/sqlitedemo/target/classes/com/example/sqlitedemo/Person.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:452) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:315) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at com.example.sqlitedemo.SqlitedemoApplication.main(SqlitedemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/Users/ubuntu/dev/javaXP/spring_boot/spring02/sqlitedemo/target/classes/com/example/sqlitedemo/Person.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:60) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:429) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:57) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
```

My other projects work well with java 16.

```
$ java -version
java version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T19:57:37+08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec
Java version: 16.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

`dependency:tree` gives this

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sqlitedemo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ sqlitedemo ---
[INFO] com.example:sqlitedemo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.21.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.38:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.38:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.16.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.3.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.14:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.3.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] \- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.16.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.821 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-02T08:11:06+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/94M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I changed the java version properly?

---

update:

I tried to add this to POM

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
        <version>9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I got this (from `mvn dependency:tree`)

```
[INFO] +- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.16.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:9.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:9.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:9.0:compile
```

and this (from `mvn clean install -e`)

```
Unsupported class file major version 60
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet
```

Comment: Did you execute a Maven `clean` and `install`?

Comment: Did you update your POM to use latest versions of Spring and other dependencies?

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you. Which part of POM needs to be updated, besides `<java.version>`

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you and yes, I've executed `mvn clean install -e` and got `ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file ...` the same error in my OP

Comment: Your spring-boot-starter-parent is too old

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact problem you have, but if you want to build with Java 16:

1. Ensure you use the good `java.version`: you already done that; https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/
2. Ensure you use either [a toolchain to select Java 16](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) or that your `PATH` or `JAVA_HOME` point to a Java 16 (eg: `java -version` or `mvn --version` should give you the version 16).
3. If you use a dependency that "fails" to see Java 16 such as ASM, ensure it is compatible: for ASM, that would be [ASM 9.0](https://asm.ow2.io/versions.html). This dependency is pulled out by Spring: use `mvn dependency:tree` to get the actual version and enforce the good version it using a `dependencyManagement`.

Also check version of spring-boot:

> Spring Boot **2.5.0 M1** Release Notes This release provides preliminary
> support for Java 16.

Either stick with older version of Java, either use 2.5.0-M1.